# How can I write a number on pdf document saved varbinary in database?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, itext

I want to write serial number on a pdf document. 
And I achieved it with below code with using itextSharp.dll.

```
public byte[] Sign(string path, string serialnumber)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);

    //iterate through all pages in source pdf
    for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
        PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pageIndex);
        pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40);
        PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
        graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.4F;
        pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
        pdfData.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE);
        pdfData.BeginText();
        pdfData.ShowTextAligned(iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, serialnumber, pageRectangle.Width - 175, pageRectangle.Height - 50, 0);
        pdfData.EndText();
    }

    pdfStamper.Close();
    memoryStream.Close();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

But I save pdf documents in database which type is varbinary(max).

So how can I write a number on a document which is saved as binary in database?

Comment: `PdfReader` has multiple constructors, one of them accepts a `byte[].` Thus, if you simply read the PDF in your database into a byte[] in memory, you can build a `PdfReader` for it and otherwise handle it as you did above.

Answer (score 0):

As @mkl mentioned, one of the other parameters of PdfReader is `byte[]`, so one can easily use binary data.